# Find a value anywhere in a read-only database

Tags: sql-server

A customer's 96GB SQL Server 2014 accounting database has about 1,000 tables, none of which has constraints or fkeys applied or is otherwise documented. I have **read only access, with basically other no rights.**

A user has sent me a screenshot showing a value that is stored *somewhere* in the database. The value is "51210000", which might also be stored as a pointer to its entry in the ACCOUNTS table, 323.

I have seen various solutions to searching an entire db, but they invariably use temporary tables, procedures, or other solutions that require write access. Can anyone offer a way to do this read-only?

Comment: Temporary tables don't require write access; they use `tempdb`.

Comment: Honestly though, this sounds like a design nightmare, and someone should be documenting the design, and setting up the constraints.

Comment: "A user has sent me a screenshot showing a value..." -- What about simply asking them from where this value comes?

Comment: I expect that an accounting database would have the value "51210000" in it many many times you'll never identify the correct instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a bit slow, but you can run these a few at a time to see where it may exist

```
SELECT CONCAT('select * from ', TABLE_NAME, ' where ', COLUMN_NAME, ' = ''51210000''')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: That's testing the column name, not the contents?

Comment: This query produces results in the form of additional queries you can copy and paste to run. It just removes the task of writing out a query for each table and subsequent column

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I added an order by and some limits (all text fields start with 's' so that helps). Running batches now, I do like the simplicity of this solution!

Comment: Ultimately I went with this solution. It did ultimately find the table, it was well hidden!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `sp_MSforeachtable`

This is certainly **NOT** fast and I would suggest testing on a smaller database.

**Example**

```
Declare @Results table (TableName varchar(500),RowData varchar(max))

Insert Into @Results
 EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT TableName=''?'' ,RowData = (Select A.* for XML Raw) FROM ? A Where (Select A.* for XML Raw) like ''%51210000%'''

Select *
 From  @Results
```

**Note:**

If 2016+, you may get a little boost by using the JSON alternative.

```
Replace  (Select A.* for XML Raw)
With     (Select A.* for JSON Path)
```

**Just for fun**

I ran a test looking for "`Consulting`" on a 17GB database (214 tables).  It took 1 minute 30 seconds to return

[image]

**EDIT - Dynamic SQL Approach**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Set @SQL=Stuff((Select 'Union All ' +Expr 
                 From  (
                        Select Expr  = 'Select Table_Schema='''+Table_Schema+''',Table_Name='''+Table_Name+''',Column_Name='''+Column_Name+''',Value=cast('+quotename(Column_Name)+' as varchar(max)) From '+quotename(Table_Schema)+'.'+quoteName(Table_Name)+' Where '+quotename(Column_Name)+' like ''%Cappe%''||'
                         From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                         Where Data_Type in ('varchar','int','float','bigint')  -- << Set Your Desired Filter
                           and Table_Name not like 'vw_%'                       -- << I'd tend to exclude views my prefix vw_
                       ) A
                 For XML Path ('')),1,10,'')
Set @SQL = replace(@SQL,'||',char(13))
Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: I see the trick here is to use a table-variable, which immediately solves the writability issue. *sigh*, I *should* have thought of that one! But one minor issue, you can't do a XMLRAW on blob or binary columns, is there a way to filter those out?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Sorry, never considered binary (not a fan).  See edit for a dynamic SQL approach.  You may have to tweak and tune.  Again performance with such techniques will suffer.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Sorry I assumed you  wanted the results in one table.   No worries.  Still pleased you found a solution that works for you.  This is why I love SO ... options, options, options  :)